# Move Gnome notification bar in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome

In 16.04, Gnome now puts all the user-configurable widgets (system-monitor, caffeine, bluetooth) in a little slid-out panel in the lower-left hand side of the screen. This is horrible and makes the widgets unusable. How do I put these back in the top-bar like they were before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the TopIcons extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/